# How to change font style font with Rmarkdown-PDF , already sent error : " Failed to find a package that contains Times New Roman"

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

It's my first Markdown report, and i try to write it directly on a PDF. I need to  use Times New Roman font but the export fail:

`Package fontspec Error: The font "Times New Roman" cannot be found.`

I've already tried these code

`font-family: Times New Roman`

or

`mainfont: Times New Roman`

or

```
header-includes:

- \usepackage{fontspec}

- \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

but none of these codes work.

Thanks !

Comment: Which engine do you use for compiling? You used both pdflatex and xelatex as tags, please advise which of both is true

Comment: Are you sure you have "Times New Roman" with this spelling installed on your system?

Comment: I use xelatex but I tried with luatex too, and both did not work ..

Comment: I think it is, but  I can't see because I work on Rstudio.cloud

Comment: Try one listed in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Comment: As for the fonts in the LaTeX font catalogue: Sticks Too, Stix (2), TeX Gyre Termes, TX Fonts, URW Nimbus Roman, and XITS are all Times (New Roman) like fonts. At least URW Nimus Roman, i.e. `mathptmx.sty`, should be available on rstudio.cloud, since it is a required part of every LaTeX distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RalfStubner has already mentioned, you can use `TeX Gyre Termes` to embed a font like `Times New Roman`.

### Install `tex-gyre`

In order to use `TeX Gyre Termes`, you need to install `tex-gyre` package from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre). If you have installed @Yihui's [`TinyTeX`](https://yihui.name/tinytex/), type the following code to R console.

```r
tinytex::tlmgr_install("tex-gyre")
```

The code above is equivalent to executing the code below in your bash.

```sh
tlmgr install tex-gyre
```

### Provide `.tex` file to specify font(s) you want

Setting `mainfont:` in the YAML header should also work. However, here I show how to set fonts by including a `.tex` file, say `font-config.tex` for instance, to the YAML section. By the `font-config.tex` file, you can configure more detailed options, like `Scale=MatchUppercase`.

In the following `font-config.tex`, `TeX Gyre Termes`, or *Times New Roman* is set as the main font (`\rmfamily`) and `TeX Gyre Heros`, so-called *Helvetica* or *Arial* is specified as the san serif font (`\sffamily`). Save the file in your current directory.

#### font-config.tex

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}

%rmfamily
\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{TeX Gyre Termes} %Times New Roman

%sffamily
\setsansfont[Scale=1]{TeX Gyre Heros} %So called Helvetica, Arial
```

### Include `font-config.tex` into the YAML header

You can call the `font-config.tex` from the YAML header, as shown below.

```
---
title: "The definitive MWE"
subtitle: "Oh, yeah"
author: "CLR"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    number_sections: true
    latex_engine: xelatex #or lualatex
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: 
        - font-config.tex
---

*Hellow world!* in Times New Roman.

\textsf{Hellow world!} in Helvetica.
```

Comment: @Quentin Lambert Happy to hear your success!! Much appreciated if you click `accept` button to show that your problem was resolved.